# create common output zip file using maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have 3 modules which are linked to a parent project similar to this.

```
root (pom.xml)
   +--- mod1 (pom.xml)
   +--- mod2 (pom.xml)
   +--- mod3 (pom.xml)
```

I have some configuration files in config folder of mod1. I have other configuration files in config folder of mod2. I want to place all these configuration files in a common folder in the output zip file.

Is this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to add [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) execution to the last module in build process (I assume in your case it is mod3) and add assembly descriptor, somewhat like this:

```
<assembly>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../mod1/config</directory>
        <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../mod2/config</directory>
        <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: This works. However how can I make changes in my java code to point to the new location