# How to change file location in java code dynamically?

Tags: java, maven

I have 3 modules which are linked to a parent project similar to this.

```
root (pom.xml)
   +--- mod1 (pom.xml)
   +--- mod2 (pom.xml)
   +--- mod3 (pom.xml)
```

I have some configuration files in config folder of mod1. I have other configuration files in config folder of mod2. I have placed all these configuration files in a common folder in the output zip file.

I now have to change the location dynamically in order to point to the new location. Is this possible?

Comment: You must elaborate your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [create common output zip file using maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882058/create-common-output-zip-file-using-maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are obtaining you configuration files using the class path, you can move the location of the files and change the class path.